# checkout onepage select address event

Tags: php, events, magento

i have to change the order total amount, whenever customer change or select the address on  checkout onepage. i dont think so there exist any magento event related to it.

Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: Which of the many objects is having its total adjusted? The increase in cost has to be associated with an order entity (`quote_item`, etc.)

Comment: Updating total amount is not problem , I need an event like - customer select the address and press continue button - at this time i have to implement my logic.

Comment: Are you sure that "Updating total amount is not problem"? There are dozens of events and methods which are involved with the AJAX request which pressing that button fires.

Comment: then what should i do to achieve